# I would like to build an app that alerts me when road traffic is high or low. Where can I get the raw data?

Tags: web-services, web-applications

I'm sitting at work, waiting for traffic to die down.  The thought occurred to me.  I know when I want to go home, why don't I have an app that watches traffic for me?  I also know that there are a lot of smart people on stackoverflow.

Where can I get live traffic data for the san francisco bay area region?  The data source should be timely, accurate, and as high resolution as possible.  I would like to build an app on top of a service, rather than watch google maps or watch another website.  I would prefer that I not have to scrape the data, but I have been know to do this in the past when no other option exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you limit yourself to the San Francisco area, there might be something available from [511.org](http://www.511.org/)

Mapquest gets their traffic information from [INRIX](http://www.inrix.com/).

Answer (score 1):

[TraffiCast](http://www.trafficcast.com/) is the definitive source, I think.

Answer (score 1):

You could check out map quest's beta api http://platform.beta.mapquest.com/traffic/ not sure if it's what you need but it's clean